# Transfer an object from controller to dao

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am getting an token from request(the token is required to identify the user) to initialize user object in interceptor. Then i want to transfer this user object to controllers(i can put the user object to httprequest and get it in controller method, is this the best practice???, i am not sure) than transfer it to service and dao layer. But i don't want to add this user object as parameter to every method between controller->service->dao. What is the best practice of this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a [request-scoped bean](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-bean-scopes-request-session-global-session-example/) to hold the token. You could reference the bean in your controller and set the token on it. Then in lower DAO layers could you reference the same bean to pull out the token. That would save having to pass the token down the method stack.

Alternatively you could use `ThreadLocal` storage directly which is effectively request scoped, but since you're using Spring, it would be cleaner and make more sense to leverage it's own request scope  functionality.